# Exception trying to create custom (named) OrderBy extension in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Consider these extensions:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<Thing> OrderByDateAndNumber(this IEnumerable<Thing> source)
{
    return source.OrderByDescending(x => x.ThingDate).ThenByDescending(x => x.ThingNumber);
}

public static IOrderedQueryable<Thing> OrderByDateAndNumber(this IQueryable<Thing> source)
{
    return source.OrderByDescending(x => x.ThingDate).ThenByDescending(x => x.ThingNumber);
}
```

This works:

```
var x = context.Things.OrderByDateAndNumber().ToList();
```

But this doesn't:

```
var y = context.Widgets.Select(w => w.Things.OrderByDateAndNumber().Count());
```

Producing the exception:

> [NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[Namespace.Thing] OrderDateAndNumber(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Namespace.Thing])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.]

I get that C# code can't be translated into a store expression. What I don't understand is why it works in the first instance (assuming this is made possible by my extension calling only calling supported `OrderBy` methods) but not in the second where I'm trying to incorporate it in a statement that uses a navigation property, i.e. `w.Things`)

Comment: Well in the first code you're not trying to pass it to `Select(this IQueryable<T>, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>>)`. The ordering part is fine - it's trying to pass that arbitrary result to `Select` that's the problem. Although note that your ordering is happening in *client* code in the first case anyway, as you're accepting an `IEnumerable<Thing>` rather than an `IQueryable<Thing>`. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Whoops. In my sleep-deprived haze I forgot to include the IQueryable extension that I also have in my code, I've revised the question.

Comment: have you tried 
context.Widgets..Select(w => w.Things.OrderByDateAndNumber().Expand().Count()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's becomes obvious if you remove the syntactic sugar of extension methods and use classic method calls:

This works:

```
var x = LinqExtensions.OrderByDateAndNumber(context.Things).ToList();
```

But this doesn't:

```
var y = context.Widgets.Select(w => 
            LinqExtensions.OrderByDateAndNumber(w.Things)).Count());
```

The first method resolves to the overload accepting an `IQueryable` and it simply returns the `IQueryable` appended with the ordering expressions.

Another way to put it is: in the first snippet, `OrderByDateAndNumber` is *outside* the expression.

In the second snippet, `OrderByDateAndNumber` resolves to the `IEnumerable` overload, because the navigation property `w.Things` is (probably) an `ICollection`. Also `OrderByDateAndNumber` is now *inside* the expression and, thus, part of an construction that should be translated into SQL.

Comment: Thanks @Gert, I think I understand and agree although ended up discarding the syntactic sugar and repeating the simple but critical for consistency ordering statements.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put.

```
Context.Things
```

**Context** is referenced within your c# method scope which has access to your extension method.

```
w => w.Things
```

**W** is just a lambda reference , and it will be evaluated **later** within Linq To entities assembly  which doesn't have access to your Extension method scope.

I find [LinqKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/) quite helpful on these cases , which has the "Expand" function.

All what it does is to translate your extension method earlier before sending it to Linq-to-Entities.

Comment: LinqKit looks promising but I didn't understand how I could use it in this case because OrderByDateAndNumber() is not an expression. I'm probably misunderstanding Linq and EntityFramework. I've given up at this stage. My code still works, I just wanted to tidy things up a bit by consolidating an OrderBy().ThenBy() clause that's used in many places. +1 for the recommendation.